Stop WKWebView from Autoplaying Media
I have a WKWebView via storyboard for a UIViewController from which I present/load urls.
I do not want any media to autoplay and thought I set the right configurations, but webView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all is never respected. The media always plays on load - whether it's inline or fullscreen.
I tried programmatically initializing WKWebView but ended up with the same result.
Any guidance would be really appreciated. Could not find a working solution already available...
My only janky workaround is to call .pauseAllMediaPlayback from the didFinish WKWebView navigation delegate function.
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        webView.pauseAllMediaPlayback()
    }
 }

